# React based Quiz Website

Tags: performance, node.js, react.js, mongodb, responsive-design

I have recently worked on a quiz application using the MERN stack. The application incorporates various features such as user authentication, quiz creation, scoring functionalities, and data management.

While I have put significant effort into implementing these features, there may be areas for improvement. I am seeking feedback from the community to help me identify any potential issues, suggest improvements, and ensure that the application follows best practices.

Some specific areas where I would appreciate feedback include Security Measures, User Experience, Code Quality, Performance, and Responsiveness across devices.

[Check out the website](https://quizer2024.netlify.app/)

[Check out the source code](https://github.com/chayansurana3/Quizer)

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from './pages/Login';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Create from './pages/Create';
import Explore from './pages/Explore';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(true);
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("Chayan Surana");
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("-");
  const [quizzes, setQuizzes] = useState([]);
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);
  const [quizBeingAttempted, setQuizBeingAttempted] = useState(false); 

  const LogIn = () => setLoggedIn(true);
  const LogOut = () => {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Do you want to logout of your account?",
      icon: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
      cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
      confirmButtonText: "Logout!"
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        setLoggedIn(false);
      }
    })
  }
  const setName = (name) => setUserName(name);
  const increaseId = () => setId(id + 1);
  const attempting = () => setQuizBeingAttempted(previousState => !previousState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkLoginStatus = async () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (token) {
        try {
          const response = await fetch("/.netlify/functions/verify", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Authorization": token
            }
          });
          if (response.status === 200) {
            const data = await response.json();
            setLoggedIn(true);
            console.log(data);
            setUserName(data.userName);
            setUserEmail(data.userEmail);
          } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        }
      }
    };
    
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/.netlify/functions/fetchQuiz");
        const data = await response.json();
        setQuizzes(data);
        console.log("Fetched all quizzes");
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching quiz data:", error);
      }
    };

    checkLoginStatus();
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <NavBar quizzes={quizzes} loggedIn={loggedIn} userName={userName} logOut={LogOut} display={!quizBeingAttempted}/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login LogIn={LogIn} setName={setName} userName={userName} userEmail={userEmail} />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp LogIn={LogIn} setName={setName} userName={userName} userEmail={userEmail} />} />
          <Route path="/create" element={<Create loggedIn={loggedIn} userName={userName} userEmail={userEmail} id={id} increaseId={increaseId} />} />
          <Route path="/explore" element={<Explore loggedIn={loggedIn} quizzes={quizzes} attempting={attempting} userName={userName} userEmail={userEmail} />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile userName={userName} userEmail={userEmail}/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Home(){
    return (
        <div className="h-screen bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-indigo-700 text-white flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <div className="text-center">
                <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold mb-12">Welcome to Quizer</h1>
                <p className="text-lg mb-12">The ultimate platform for creating, sharing, and taking a quiz.</p>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
                    <Link to="/create" className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-extrabold py-4 px-8 rounded-lg shadow-md mr-4">Create a Quiz</Link>
                    <Link to="/explore" className="bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-700 text-white font-extrabold py-4 px-8 rounded-lg shadow-md">Explore Quizzes</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Signup.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const User = require("./models/userSchema");

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.y0mzlcb.mongodb.net/${process.env.USER_DB}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`)
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error));
    
    const { userName, email, password } = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser) return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "User already exists" })
    };

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const newUser = new User({
      userName: userName,
      email: email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    await newUser.save();

    return {
      statusCode: 201,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "User created successfully" })
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Internal server error" })
    };
  }
};
```

Do check out the rest of the source code. [Click Here](https://github.com/chayansurana3/Quizer)

Comment: I read "kw-eye-zer" with a long "I" sound, and "quizzer" with a short "I". Consider adding a 2nd "Z" to the name.